# Pass Parameter to SimplifiedModule

Tags: extjs, shopware

Background:

After struggling a while with shopware and extJs i decided to use a SimplifiedModule because i cannot figure out how i can use a canvas with js to get some user input. Simplified explained, i want to display a canvas where the user can click at a point and save that coordinate in the database.

Problem:

I need to pass a ID to the Simplified module so it can display the right data, and handle them correctly. Neither the Shopware Documentation nor the Sourcecode lead to me to the answer.

Question:

So what do i have to do, to pass a parameter that i can use in my Controller/Template?

```
Shopware.ModuleManager.createSimplifiedModule(
    "TestModule",
    {
        "title": "My Title",
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the recommended way, but it works if i add the params to the module name:

```
Shopware.ModuleManager.createSimplifiedModule(
    "TestModule?param1=a&param2=b",
    {
        "title": "My Title",
    }
);
```